# ...(as / for) a deposit

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was wondering which preposition works here properly?

> You need to save money Tamara! I think you as a divorcee who has got a kid should **put a little aside ....... a deposit** every once in a while. Even seemingly these small amounts of cash can come in handy someday.

a. as 
b. for

I think that "as" is the correct choice although I need your confirmation.

Comment: Either would work. My instinct would be to go with "for". It sounds a bit more natural to me, probably since "deposit" even as a noun is closely linked to the verb action of depositing something. "As" is also a valid grammatical choice, though. Just gives a slightly different tense to the future action, perhaps.